# not able to get value from edittext

Tags: android

I've the following code.

```
final Button Submit= (Button) findViewById(R.id.SubmitButton);
            Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {

                chatbox=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Chatbox);   <-- error
                String data=chatbox.getText().toString();
                Log.i("chama",data);

                HashMap<String,String> hashMap=new HashMap<String,String>();    
                        hashMap.put("You",chatbox.getText().toString());    //insert username(You) value in chatbox to hashmap

                        adminChat.add(hashMap);                                 //insert hashMap in arraylist
                        ShowListView(adminChat);                            //pass it to listview

                        sendHttpRequest("set", "admin", "You" ,chatbox.getText().toString(),clientEmail,UserAdminChatActivity.LastShowingChatDate);                   

         }});
```

It is declared in the xml like this

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Chatbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/SubmitButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/SubmitButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/SubmitButton"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text" >
</EditText>
```

The logcat gives the following error:

```
07-15 17:40:20.083: E/AndroidRuntime(5503): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 17:40:20.083: E/AndroidRuntime(5503): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 17:40:20.083: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at com.app.ServerClient.UserAdminChatActivity$2.onClick(UserAdminChatActivity.java:52)
07-15 17:40:20.083: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
07-15 17:40:20.083: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
07-15 17:40:20.083: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-15 17:40:20.083: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-15 17:40:20.083: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-15 17:40:20.083: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
07-15 17:40:20.083: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 17:40:20.083: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-15 17:40:20.083: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-15 17:40:20.083: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-15 17:40:20.083: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: i've pasted the whole onclick() event.

Comment: you are calling this piece of code after calling `setContentView` ?

Comment: @Mj1992 : try after moving `chatbox=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Chatbox);`   line before final Button `Submit= (Button) findViewById(R.id.SubmitButton);` line
 and check EditView for null before using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
String data=""; 
chatbox=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Chatbox);
if(chatbox.getText().toString()!=null)
    data=chatbox.getText().toString();
```

Also, make sure the EditText you are referring to is in the same xml file you are using to map with your activity via `setContentView()`

Comment: another edit. see if that helps. though it will kill your logic, if the user enters null values, but see if it gets you rid of the error. Specify some checks later on (for non-null values)

Answer (score 1):

You should do this

```
chatbox= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Chatbox);
```

outside of `onClick` method. This makes no sence for me. Your `widget` should be initialized immediately after you will set `contentView`.

So

```
...
protected EditText chatbox;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedOnInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedOnInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   chatbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Chatbox);
   ...
   chatbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
         String data=chatbox.getText().toString();
         ...
      }
   });
}
```